# custom UITableViewCell know what cell was a check box modified

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a custom cell that have a check box,

all is working fine,  the checkboxes get check according to a dictionary that I pass to my subclassed UITableViewCell,

but now I need to pass to the class that have the table view the exact cell that my check box was modified so I can set my mutable dictionary with the new checked or unchecked state for that particular cell,

So how to do this?, shall I use a delegate?, this is fine, but the question is, how do I know what cell was my check box modified at?

Comment: This should help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750753/uitableviewcell-accessory-type-checked-on-tap-set-other-unchecked

Comment: Hi @MarkM, I thougth of this, but my didSelectRow, doesnt get called, Im showing another view controller on didSelectRow, I even do a log but this doesnt get called on check of the cell,

Comment: Yeah, didSelect only gets called when nothing else consumes the touch on the cell. If the cell contains a button, textField, switch, slider, etc... then that control will consume the touch (if the touch is inside it) and stop didSelect from firing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a delegate like this...

MyCell.h

```
@protocol MyCellDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)cellCheckBoxWasChanged:(MyCell *)cell;

@end

@interface MyCell : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <MyCellDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

MyCell.m

```
@implementation MyCell

- (void)checkBoxChanged
{
    [self.delegate cellCheckBoxWasChanged:self];
}

@end
```

Then to find the index you can do...

TableViewController.m

```
- (void)cellCheckBoxWasChanged:(MyCell *)cell
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    // do something to your array.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you pass the UITableViewCell also in the delegate method as `self`.

So with that cell, you could get the indexpath by

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
```

Answer (score 1):

set the tag Value of each Checkboxes depending on the cells Indexpath in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

```
   UIButton *checkboxes = customCell.checkButton
   [checkboxes setTag:indexPath.row];
```

then  in buttons action method.

check the senders.Tag value to get the exact row of the button pressed

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0]];
```

Comment: `cellForRowAtIndexPath` required an NSIndexPath not an int!

Comment: What if you have more than 1 section?

Comment: there are many work around's to achieve that, you can have different IBAction's for buttons of diffrent sections, the other way can be,just go on increasing the tag number.and in the ibaction check if(tag>X && tag<Y)set section=z, third workarround can be to set the tag in such a way that it contains both row and section (eg: tag= 0302 ie the third row of 2nd section)and handle the seperation of row and section in the action.

Comment: There are better solutions that involve using OO techniques I think.

Comment: defiantly there may be, but i just posted what worked best for me.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this -

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

 if([[[Usercontacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"isChecked"]isEqualToString:@"NO"])
        {
            [checkUncheckBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked box.png" ]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
             checkUncheckBtn.tag=1; 
        }
        else
        {
            [checkUncheckBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked box.png" ]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
              checkUncheckBtn.tag=2; 
        }
       [checkUncheckBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(checkUncheckBtnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}
```

and when you perform `checkUncheckBtnPressed`: method it looks like

```
-(void)checkUncheckBtnPressed:(id)sender
{

    UIButton *btn=(UIButton*)sender;
    UITableViewCell *cell =(UITableViewCell *) [sender superview] ;
    NSIndexPath *_indxpath = [createGroupContactsTableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    if(btn.tag==1)
    {
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked box.png" ]forState:UIControlStateNormal];   
        btn.tag=2;
        [[Usercontacts objectAtIndex:_indxpath.row]setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"isChecked"];
    }
    else 
    {

        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked box.png" ]forState:UIControlStateNormal];   
         btn.tag=1;
        [[Usercontacts objectAtIndex:_indxpath.row]setObject:@"NO" forKey:@"isChecked"];

    }


}
```

Comment: `UITableViewCell *cell =(UITableViewCell *) [sender superview] ;` isn't reliable. The checkbox is more likely to be a subview of the tablesView's contentView and possibly even nested deeper.

Comment: yeah it is possible but according to my project i have created according to my need.If you wish you can nest more

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative to having the Cells listen to events from the checkBoxes and forward them to the UITableViewController using the delegate pattern:

Have the UITableViewController listen to events from the checkBoxes and use the following code to determine the NSIndexPath of the cell:

```
@implementation UITableView (MyCategory)

-(NSIndexPath*)indexPathOfCellComponent:(UIView*)component {
    if([component isDescendantOfView:self] && component != self) {
        CGPoint point = [component.superview convertPoint:component.center toView:self];
        return [self indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];
    }
    else {
        return nil;
    }
}
@end
```