# How to get the indexPath of value component in a custom cell in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, custom-cell

I need get the `indexPath.row` of a components (switch, checks..) located inside my `CustomCellS` class. I'm trying code below in custom cell class, but I get an error:

```
class CustomCellS: UITableViewCell{
    @IBOutlet weak var switch: UISwitch!

    var cell: UITableViewCell = switch.superview as UITableViewCell //crash
    var tableView: UITableView = cell.superview as UITableView
    var indexPath: NSIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)

  ...
 }
```

> Error: Thread 1: EXC_Breakpoint(code=EXC_i386_BPT, subcode=0x0)

How can get the indexPath.row of this components?
Thanks!

Comment: Check out my answer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520151/custom-uitableviewcell-know-what-cell-was-a-check-box-modified/16520522#16520522

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't build at all. `switch` is a keyword. If you really want to use this word as a variable name you should put it inside backticks.

It seems that all you're trying to do is to access the `indexPath` of the cell inside it. In that case you can have a property for it and set in when you create the cell in your `tableView` method.

But from a design point of view, `indexPath` is something that your `tableView` uses to keep track of things and your cell should usually be 'blind' to it because it's not its concern (and that's why `UITableViewCell` doesn't have such property built-in.) You'll probably be able to do what you need to do without exposing unnecessary information to your cell.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that the switch's view is very likely not the `UITableViewCell` itself. `UITableViewCell` has a few subviews, one of which is its `contentView`. That contentView is likely the superview of your UISwitch. However, this is easily worked around; if you have a cell that contains the switch, then by definition you already have a reference to the cell itself.

The second problem is that the cell's superview is not guaranteed to be the tableView. If you really need a cell to have a reference to the tableview, then you should probably add the tableView as a weak property and pass a reference to the tableview when you create the cell.

Comment: Is there any code for I see this? I don't know If I need reference this in tableViewCOntroller or in CustomCellCOntroller and How do this..