# Check a specific row in a tablecell in Xcode

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I would like how to (auto)check a row number 0 of my tableCell when a variable is equal to something and uncheck all the others, programmatically.

For example:
I have a language view, and I have this tableView:

English
Spanish
Italian

I would like if I am using english, automatically check the row number 0 of my table.
i only want the symbol of check appears in the screen.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The simplest answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750753/uitableviewcell-accessory-type-checked-on-tap-set-other-unchecked?rq=1

Comment: Yes, but I need to access the properties of a specifisc row in my table