# Check and uncheck the same UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need to uncheck cell in my tableView. Like a checkbox, once i pressed a cell it stay selected, if i pressed again the same cell it stay unselected. Is it possible?

All I found is some method for deselecting cells

```
[table deselectRowAtIndexPath:NSIndexPath animated:YES];
```

but it's not useful

upd:
i don't need to check many cells, all i need to uncheck cell if a tap on selected cell, and if i tap on other(unselected) cell, selected should change state to unselected(it's already work by default in cells)

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableViewCell Accessory Type Checked on Tap & Set other unchecked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750753/uitableviewcell-accessory-type-checked-on-tap-set-other-unchecked)

Comment: Check this answer, it should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750753/uitableviewcell-accessory-type-checked-on-tap-set-other-unchecked

Comment: -allowsMutipleSelection https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/allowsMultipleSelection

Comment: @Andrea i don't need to check many cells, all i need to uncheck cell if a tap on selected cell, and if i tap on other(unselected) cell, selected should change state to unselected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where your datasource is load
do this

```
arrSelected = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i <arrSong.count; i++) {
    [arrSelected addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
}
```

In your cell for indexpath do this

```
if ([[arrSelected objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue] == YES) {
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
}
else{
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
}
```

To select/deselect do thisin you tableview:didselect

```
    if ([[arrSelected objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue] == YES) {
        [arrSelected replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
    }
    else{
        [arrSelected replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
    }
```

Comment: good, but works only if i add [tableView reloadData];

if ([[arrSelected objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue] == YES) {
        [arrSelected replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
[tableView reloadData];
    }

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way, but it's not the best: 
In didSelectRow, before setingTheAccesoryType you just have to call:

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

and this will deselect all the rows all the rows, and after that check the currentCell,

in cellForRow you set the accesoryType of the cell to none.

Answer (score 0):

```
ios swift
```

1.  by default all the cell are inactive state so store cell in dictionary

```
var indexPathCheckmark = [Int: Bool]()

// set all the values initally false for check mark
                    for var index = 0 ; index < self.listOfOldApps.count ; index++ {
                        self.indexPathCheckmark[index] = false
                    }
```

2. inside your didSelectRowAtIndexPath using following

   ```
   // set a check marker for all cell required
       let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
       if (indexPathCheckmark[indexPath.row] == false) {
           indexPathCheckmark[indexPath.row] = true
           cell?.accessoryView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "done-active"))
       } else {
           indexPathCheckmark[indexPath.row] = false
           cell?.accessoryView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "done"))
       }
   ```