# Scrolling in UITableView makes UIImages appear on cells where they do not exsist

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a strange problem with the UITableView. I add a checkmark image to all the cells that does not have the date property set to the current day. When the tableview is populated it seems to be working fine since the first elements, that has no date, does not show the checkmark. When I scroll down to the first cell with a correct date, the checkmark is showed. When I scroll back up, the checkmark is showed in all the cells. Why does this happen?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"InventoryingSearchResultCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault;
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        UIView *selectionColor = [[UIView alloc] init];
        selectionColor.backgroundColor = myAppDelegate.config.appTheme;
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectionColor;

        // create accessory view
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"u12_normal.png"];
        cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    }

    // fill in data
    NSDictionary *item = [searchResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *inventoryDate;
    inventoryDate = [item valueForKey:@"InventoryDate"];
    if (![inventoryDate isEqual:[NSNull null]]){
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
        NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:inventoryDate];

        if ([self hasBeenInventoried:date]) {
            UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tick.png"];
            UIImageView *view1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16, 40, 16, 16)];
            view1.image = image1;
            [cell.accessoryView addSubview:view1];
        }
    } else {
        inventoryDate = @"";
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: please read the documentation from apple about tableView reusable cells

Comment: and to fix it you shoult set the image of the imageView to nothing.. something like [UIImage imageNamed:@""];, everytime before adding another image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happening because you're reusing cells. In the event that the checkmark needs to be shown, you're adding it to your cell. However, when it is NOT required, you're not setting the image to blank/nil.

When a cell is reused that already has this image on it, you never tell it to remove the checkmark.

I would recommend adding your `view1` accessory subview when your cell is `nil` so that the subview always exists. Then, if your inventory requires the checkmark, set the image. If it does not require the checkmark, set the image to `nil`.

---

Side note: in general, only add subviews to a reusable cell when the cell is `nil`. If you add subviews to existing cells, there's a good chance that you'll end up having multiples of that subview on your cell.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is for reusing cell property of UITableView. 
so remove this line from your code:

```
    // create accessory view
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"u12_normal.png"];
    cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
```

place it in the else part where you change this image

you can also see the link

[Check and uncheck the same UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25363974/check-and-uncheck-the-same-uitableviewcell)