# Disclosure indicator to specific cell in static TableView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, indexpath

I created a static TableView and I would like to add or remove a disclosure indicator depending if we are consulting our own account or a guest account.

This is what I would like :

```
let index = IndexPath(row: 4, section: 0)

let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: index)
if currentUser {
   cell.accessoryType = .none
   //cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}
```

I tried to put it in the viewDidLoad function but it didn't work. I tried cellForRowAt indexPath also and same result.

How could I do that?

Comment: and is there an else? that just removes the accessory ... where do you set it?

Comment: If the cells are static use  `IBOutlet`s to access the cells directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are working with static cells so `cellForRow` will not get called. Instead, simply drag connect your cell and set it up, like this

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just check if you want to show disclosure indicator in cellForRowAt indexPath method.

```
if (wantsToShow){ // Your condition goes here
   cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator
}
else{
   cell.accessoryType = .none
}
```

That's it.

Comment: The problem is that it's a static TableView and I would like do this only on the cell [0, 4] ...

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code in cellForRowTableView code

It will work for you

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{ 
    if currentUser {
     // Own Account
       cell.accessoryType = .none
       //cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }else{
     //Guest Account
     cell.accessoryType =.checkmark
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift**

> Specific cell

```
if indexPath.row == 1 {
    cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = .none
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To add accessory on a specific static cell, I used tableView, cellForRowAt but i couldn't access a reference to UITableViewCell.

Then i found super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)

So here is my code:
Assuming you know the specific indexpath you want:

```
    var indexPathSort = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
    var indexPathPrice = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 1)


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)
            if indexPath == indexPathSort || indexPath == indexPathPrice {

                cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
            }
            return cell
        }
```